# Error in Parameters of Stored Procedure when Dynamic SQL is used

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using **Oracle Sql Developer** to write a Stored Proc, which accepts a list of values separated by "," (**dynamic sql**) and use this variable in "**in**" clause to fire a query from a table.

But i am ending up with an error at

```
@p_case_nbr       varchar2(100),
```

**Error(4,5): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "@" when expecting one of the following:          current delete exists prior**

The SP used:

```
    create or replace
procedure TEST_PROC
(   
    @p_case_nbr       varchar2(100),
    p_out_case_nbr    out varchar2 
)
as
  cursor test_cur is
      select t.COLUMN1
      from test_table t
      where t.column1 in (@p_case_nbr);

      test_cur_line  test_cur%ROWTYPE;
begin

p_out_case_nbr := null;

  open test_cur;
    LOOP
      FETCH test_cur INTO test_cur_line;
      EXIT WHEN test_cur%NOTFOUND;

      p_out_case_nbr := p_out_case_nbr || ' ' || test_cur_line.COLUMN1;
      dbms_output.put_line(test_cur_line.COLUMN1);

   end loop;
  close test_cur; 

  dbms_output.put_line('Final Value ' || p_out_case_nbr);
  dbms_output.put_line('SP Completed Succesfully');
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

In `ORACLE` no need of giving `@` before varibles
Just try to remove the `@` from `@p_case_nbr` where ever specified and try once again 
and also no need of specifying the size of the parameter like `@p_case_nbr varchar2(100)`
just give `@p_case_nbr varchar`

Comment: Hi,
I tried this approach without @ symbol in oracle, but this didn't help.
It always treated the string as a direct value to search for, instead of **preparing a Dynamic query**.

But when i tried to debug to check what was the value passed to p_case_nbr. It was passed as a perfect ',' separated values.

`p_case_nbr '00100999996544413869','00100999996544414064','00100999996544413470' VARCHAR2.`

However the query thought the values with "," is the entire value to search for.

Comment: what do you mean by `dynamic sql` in you program 
if you want values to be checked at `where t.column1 in (p_case_nbr);` then while calling the proc just pass
`'00100999996544413869,00100999996544414064,00100999996544413470'`​

Comment: I am not facing any error if i remove @ symbol but there is no output either.
I tried this with `set serveroutput on;
variable out_var1 varchar2;
exec TEST_PROC ('00100999996544413869,00100999996544414064,00100999996544413470', :out_var1 );
print :out_var1;`
and with 
`exec TEST_PROC ('''00100999996544413869'',''00100999996544414064'',''00100999996544413470''', :out_var1 ); `
but there was still no output. however this query fetches me the result when i run it manually `select t.COLUMN1 from test_table t where t.column1 in ('00100999996544413869','00100999996544414064','00100999996544413470')`